# Fresh installation of Windows Server 2008 and IIS serving up blank pages

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7.5, asp.net

I've just set up a new web server, running windows 2008 with IIS 7.5. I'm trying to set up a few websites within IIS. These websites run fine on my local machine but now that I've uploaded them to this new server and try to view them, IIS is serving me up a blank page (with no html whatsoever).

When I check the network tab in chrome it seems I'm getting an internal server error 500. I've tried following this advice: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640526/detailed-500-error-message-asp-iis-7-5 however I still receive the blank pages.

I've also checked my logs in inetpub and they simply return this:

2015-03-28 19:05:23 127.0.0.1 GET / - 80 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/41.0.2272.101+Safari/537.36 500 21 13 5

I'm finding it very difficult to figure out the problem because I can't find any meaningful error messages anywhere. Is anyone able to help?

Answer (score 1):

The fact that your receiving a 5xx error indicates it's a server-side error, so I'd start by [temporarily] enabling errors to be viewable at the client, see [iis.net](http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/running-classic-asp-applications-on-iis-7-and-iis-8/classic-asp-script-error-messages-no-longer-shown-in-web-browser-by-default)

This *should* point you in the right direction, or at least give you a better idea of what's failing.

Comment: Thanks, I have already seen that page and tried switching 'send errors to browser' to true, but it's made no difference.

I'm not really sure what to try now...

Comment: OK, my next steps would be to create a simple, static HTML page and ensure that's being served OK.  Then, if that's working, I'd use good old Process Monitor (see https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896645.aspx).  Set the filtering to "process name is w3wp.exe" and see what files are being referenced, Etc.  Oh, and add the "User name" column to the output.

Comment: Thanks Simon. I already did the first step ie. confirmed I could see static html pages.. but I'll have a look at your other suggestions

Comment: Finally solved it :-)

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved it!

The issue was to do with Asp.Net not being set up correctly. I just did [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6846544/how-to-fix-handler-pagehandlerfactory-integrated-has-a-bad-module-managedpip) and everything started working. Hopefully this'll help someone else out there...